# Mutable borrow in multiple closures

Tags: rust

I have two closure that reference and modify an outer variable.

```rust
let mut i: i32 = 0;

let mut add = || {
    i += 1;
};
let mut sub = || {
    i -= 1;
};
add();
sub();
```

The following code won't compile that produces the error below:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `i` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:14:19
   |
11 |     let mut add = || {
   |                   -- first mutable borrow occurs here
12 |         i += 1;
   |         - first borrow occurs due to use of `i` in closure
13 |     };
14 |     let mut sub = || {
   |                   ^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
15 |         i -= 1;
   |         - second borrow occurs due to use of `i` in closure
16 |     };
17 |     add();
   |     --- first borrow later used here
```

How to use mutable borrow in multiple closures?

Comment: You can't, like the compiler is telling you. Now, what do you _really_ want?

Comment: If you want to mutate a variable from two closures, you can use interior mutability.

Comment: In this case, you can just move `sub()` after the call to `add()`.

Comment: You can make the closure take `&mut i32` as an argument so that it doesn't capture its environment at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you described it, you can't. The `add`-closure takes an exclusive ("mutable") borrow of `i` at the point where the closure is constructed. The compiler *guarantees* that `add` is the *only* way to observe `i` until that borrow ends. Yet `sub` does exactly the same thing: It tries to borrow `i` exclusively, and that borrow is used after the call to `add()`. But there is no way that both

- `add` has exclusive access to `i` via it's mutable borrow
- `sub` has an exclusive borrow of `i`, which is exclusive while `add` is being called, so it can be used by `sub` *after* `add` has been called

can be true at the same time.

Depending on your use-case, and if you can't avoid this problem altogether, either restructure your code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut i: i32 = 0;

    let mut add = || {
        i += 1;
    };

    add();

    // The mutable borrow by `add` has ended, so `i` is free to get borrowed again

    let mut sub = || {
        i -= 1;
    };

    sub();
}
```

or use a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to avoid having to use mutable borrows:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let i: RefCell<i32> = RefCell::new(0);

    let add = || {
        *i.borrow_mut() += 1;
    };

    let sub = || {
        *i.borrow_mut() -= 1;
    };

    add(); // 1
    sub(); // 0
    add(); // 1
    add(); // 2

    assert_eq!(*i.borrow(), 2);
}
```

Notice that by using a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), the bindings `add`/`sub` are no longer declared `mut`, as the closures use immutable ("shared") borrows of `i`; there is a runtime-check embedded in `RefCell` that checks if `i` is in fact exclusively borrowed while the closures execute. For instance, it is conceivable that `sub` calls `add` while it is executing, leading to a situation that is statically guarantee to not occur in the code you pasted: Two aliasing + mutable access paths to the same variable; as written above, `RefCell` would `panic!` to guarantee at runtime that this does not occur.

Answer (score -1):

restructuring your code a little bit it works!

```
fn main() {
    let mut i: i32 = 0;

    let add = |mut j| {
        j += 1;
        j
    };
    let sub = |mut j| {
       j -= 1;
       j
    };
    i = add(i);
    i = sub(i);
    println!("{}", i); // 0
}
```